# When I run unstructued in python it raises permissionerror winerror 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, permission-denied

Python version:
3.10.10 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:39:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
os:
win32

```
from unstructured.partition.pdf import partition_pdf


elements = partition_pdf("test.pdf")

print("\n\n".join([str(el) for el in elements]))
```

When I run unstructured to parsing pdf, python raises winerror 5 I have allowed all permission

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path        
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code       
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\**\OneDrive\GitHub\chat-your-data\ingest_data_tabula.py", line 4, in <module>
    elements = partition_pdf("test.pdf")
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured\partition\pdf.py", line 50, in partition_pdf
    return partition_pdf_or_image(
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured\partition\pdf.py", line 102, in partition_pdf_or_image
    layout_elements = _partition_pdf_or_image_local(
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured\partition\pdf.py", line 174, in _partition_pdf_or_image_local
    process_file_with_model(filename, template, is_image=is_image)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 239, in process_file_with_model
    else DocumentLayout.from_file(
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 72, in from_file
    page = PageLayout.from_image(
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 193, in from_image
    page.get_elements()
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 147, in get_elements
    elements = self.get_elements_from_layout(inferred_layout)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 159, in get_elements_from_layout
    elements = [
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 160, in <listcomp>
    get_element_from_block(
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 282, in get_element_from_block
    text = aggregate_by_block(block, image, pdf_objects, ocr_strategy)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 307, in aggregate_by_block
    text = ocr(text_region, image)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\unstructured_inference\inference\layout.py", line 336, in ocr
    return tesseract.ocr_agent.detect(cropped_image)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\layoutparser\ocr\tesseract_agent.py", line 122, in detect
    res = self._detect(image)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\layoutparser\ocr\tesseract_agent.py", line 89, in _detect
    res["text"] = pytesseract.image_to_string(
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  File "c:\Users\**\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 901, in new_CreateProcess
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(app_name, cmd_line, *args)
PermissionError: [WinError 5]
```

I have allowed all permission for python and all conda enviorments, but still raise this error. Is it something wrong with pytesseract?

Comment: This looks like a problem with your environment, or possibly with whatever you are using to run your code.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this poblem, it was caused by the pytesseract hadn't related to the tesseract. Just edit the path of tesseract in pytesseract.py file.